# Jackson not parsing all fields when proguard is enabled

Tags: java, android, jackson, proguard

I have a model class which I parse using Jackson.

```
public class MyModel {

   private String x;
   private String y;

   @JsonProperty("zzzz")
   private String z;

   public String getX() { return x; }
   public String getY() { return y; }
   public String getZ() { return z; } 
}
```

The JSON returned has keys "x", "y" and "zzzz". When I run this without proguard enabled, it works perfectly fine and I am able to read the value of all three variables.

When I run proguard, I am able to get only "z" and the others are null.

Am I expected to add JsonProperty("field_name") for all my fields even if the key name is the same as the field name?

I am using the latest jackson libs (2.4.2).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**MyModel is an immutable class**. There must be some way to initialize the states of MyModel.

In order to deserialize json to MyModel object, there should be some mechanism to set the values of x, y and z(or whatever fields you need).

Either you can **provide setters to these fields** or you can **use @JsonProperty("json_attribue")** to properly set these states of MyModel object.

I would prefer to achieve this as below-

```
public class MyModel {

  private String x;
  private String y;
  private String z;

  @JsonCreator
  public MyModel(@JsonProperty("x")String x, @JsonProperty("y")String y, @JsonProperty("zzzz")String z) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.z = z;
   }

  public String getX() { return x; }
  public String getY() { return y; }
  public String getZ() { return z; }

}
```

**Using @JsonCreator our constructor will be used in deserialization process.**

Comment: Perfect. Do you know how this works with proguard? Should I keep these model classes/annotations in my proguard settings?

Comment: Also, the parsing seems to work even when I don't specify the JsonProperty annotation. Is this because the variable name = field name?